# How extension names is handled in Japanese (Sr, Jr, III, IV)

Tags: names

I have an extension name (III) and i have trouble converting my name to japanese. Please help.

Comment: Is this about converting you name for legal documents or just for everyday communication with people?

Answer (score 8):

II, III, IV... would be 「２世{せい}」「３世{せい}」「４世{せい}」, ... as in:

> Johann Strauss II　→ 「ヨハン・シュトラウス**２世{せい}**」

Junior, senior would be 「ジュニア」「シニア」, as in:

> Martin Luther King, Jr. → 「マーティン・ルーサー・キング・**ジュニア**」